# Binary Time Series Forcasting Using LSTM

Tags: lstm

I am working on binary time series forecasting problem. My input data is binary time sequence history (daily) of some patients features (Ex: 1 0 1 1 0) and the output is a binary classification (ex: 1 : feeling good or 0: Not). I applied LSTM technique but when I compared the Y_Predicted values as continuous (Ex: 0.8 , 0.56, 0.92 ….) Does that make any sense ? Do you have any recommendation regarding ( # input nodes, activation function, and # units at the dense layer )
Thanks

Comment: You should round the Y_pred  `if y_pred >0.5 then 1 else 0` and you get the predicted result that you want

Comment: Thanks for the hint

Comment: this worked for you? should I added as the correct answer?

Comment: Yes it did,
but also I am thinking of what kind of activation functions like (Relu, smd, or SoftMax) that could lead to results closer to binary